# Convergence or divergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \sin(\pi/n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $ u_{n} = \sin \! \left( \dfrac{\pi}{n} \right) $, where $ n \in \Bbb{N} $, and consider the series $ \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} u_{n} $. Which of the following is/are true?

(a) $ \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} u_{n} $ is convergent.

(b) $ \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} u_{n} $ is divergent.

(c) $ \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} u_{n} $ is absolutely convergent.

(d) $ u_{n} \to 0 $ as $ n \to \infty $.

Now, $ n \to \infty $ implies $ \dfrac{\pi}{n} \to 0 $, so $ u_{n} = \sin \! \left( \dfrac{\pi}{n} \right) \to 0 $. Also, from the graph of $ \sin $, it looks like this sequence will tend to $ 0 $.

I am not sure about the series options — whether they are all wrong or some are right, and why so.

Comment: option $b)$ is true.

Comment: @Ganymede :  is $d$)  wrong  ?

Comment: No....(d) is correct...(b) is also correct...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For $x\le\frac\pi2$, concavity implies $\frac2\pi x\le\sin(x)\le x$.

[image]

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac\pi n\right)
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sin\left(\frac\pi n\right)\\
&\ge\frac2\pi\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac\pi n\\
&=2\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1n
\end{align}
$$
which diverges.

Furthermore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac\pi n\right)\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac\pi n=0
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

Take , $v_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Then use comparison test.

Answer (score 2):

$sin(\frac{\pi}{n})$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\frac{\pi}{n}$ so it behaves like the harmonic series which is divergent.

Comment: "equivalent to"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis

Comment: I though that the word "equivalent" in a context like this one has a canonical meaning.   Are you ok with "asymptotically equivalent" ?

Comment: yes, I like that wording better. I think this was a minor point anyway.

Comment: As long as we know what we're talking about the rest is just vocab ... anyway I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin \frac{\pi}{n} \sim \frac{\pi}{n}$ as $n \to \infty$, and since $\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{\pi}{n}$ diverges,
by the limit comparison test we see that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\sin \frac{\pi}{n}$ diverges.